# how to evaluate an equation with python

Tags: python, math, equation

I am new to programming and I want to write a python-(2.7) program to evaluate this equation for different values of `theta`:

```
    D(theta) = Acos**2(theta)+Bcos(theta)+C       ;
```

'theta' is an angle and there are 500 values arranged in a column.

My current attempt is

```
import math

x = float("-60")
A = 9.5
B = -1.6
C = 1.8
D=A*math.cos**2(x)+B*math.sin(x)+C
print
```

Comment: You need to give some details about what you've already tried, how far you have got and what *specifically* you need help with.

Comment: I tried this, first to solve the equation for one values as below,           import math
x = float("-60");
A = 9.5;
B = -1.6;
C = 1.8;
D=A*math.cos**2(x)+B*math.sin(x)+C
print

Comment: "500 values arranged in a column" sounds like you want to evaluate something 500 times, not solve a single equation.

Comment: It looks like you want to evaluate the expression for various values of theta. That's totally different to solving an equation. BTW, the `math` library trig functions expect the argument to be given in radians, not degrees.

Comment: Also you want `print(D)` ... Just `print` will merely print an empty line.

Comment: Thnx for your reply. By using this equation for values 500 means I have run the program 500 times and then the results I have to plot, but that I can handle.

Comment: yes Sir, you are right. I am sorry. It is not theta it is phi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over values like this:

```
for x in [-60.0, -45.0, -30.0]:  # etc; notice how the .0 specifies a float
    print('D({0}) = {1}'.format(x, A*math.cos(x)**2+B*math.sin(x)+C))
```

If you intend for the output to be machine-readable, maybe change the format string to something like `'{0},{1}'` for simple CSV output.

Just `print` will print nothing (well, or actually an empty line).

In Python, `cos` is the function which calculates things; you cannot exponentiate this object, but you can call it and exponentiate its result; thus `cos(x)**2` rather than `cos**2(x)` (which makes as little sense as doing, say, `import**2` and then trying to use the result as a function which you pass `x` to).

Comment: The formula doesn't contain a `sin`, but the code does...

Comment: @tripleee can you check my edit, make sure you're happy with it

Comment: @NickA Perfectly happy; thanks!

Comment: @tripleee oops, meant to be a +, not a -, fixed that, now I'm getting same results as wolfram alpha for the actual equation(`D(theta) = Acos2(theta) + Bcos(theta) + C`, upvoted, can be checked with `9.5*cos^2(-60rad)-1.6*cos(-60rad)+1.8` on wolfram

Comment: Dear tripleee,   the thing, I was want say is as follows and i think your guidance has helped me.                                                                   
for x in [-130, -129, -128, -127, -126, -125, -124, -123, -122, -121, -120, -119, -118, -117, -116, -115, -114, -113, -112, -111, -110, -109, -108, -107, -106, -105, -104, -103, -102, -101]:  # etc; notice how the .0 specifies a float
    print('D({0}) = {1}'.format(x, A*(0.5 + math.cos(2*x)/2) + B*math.cos(x) + C))

Comment: and I got the results. You are right, there are no columns and rows in python code, I was forgetting this.

Comment: If it's a monotonic series, try `for x in range(-130, 0): x=float(x)` etc

Comment: What's the reason for using `0.5 + math.cos(2*x)/2` instead of directly translating the formula as `math.cos(x)**2`?

Comment: Because that's not what the mathematical notation "cos^2" means (I was informed).

Comment: @tripleee: You were informed wrong, then. :-) That's exactly what that notation means, at least in this context. (You can easily check that for any given `x`, `math.cos(x)**2` and `0.5 + 0.5 * math.cos(2*x)` give the same value, at least up to floating-point error.)

Comment: Thanks. I have reverted the code to use the original formula.